# validate and submit html form required inputs using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form which contains inputs with `required` tag. It normally validates when I click on an input of type `submit`.

But I wanted to be able to initiate that process programmatically using javascript. or when an element outside of the form is clicked.

**Is this possible? how can I do this?**

```js
function validateAndSubmit(){
  //what can I do here to initiate same process?
  
  //tried

  document.querySelector("form").submit() //this one submits without validating

  document.querySelector("#submitter").click() //no such function as this
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input required placeholder="name"/>
  <input id="submitter" type="submit"/>
</form>

<button onClick=validateAndSubmit()>Send</button>
```

I want to do this from other event handler functions too. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first focus on the form with the [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) method:

```js
function validateAndSubmit(){
  document.querySelector("form").focus()
  document.querySelector("#submitter").click()
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input required placeholder="name"/>
  <input id="submitter" type="submit"/>
</form>

<button onClick=validateAndSubmit()>Send</button>
```